# PHP setcookie function to remember the selected BackGround and Text Color

Tags: php

I have written this code which submits to its own page. This code will allow the user to set cookies for his desired text and background color. Unfortunately, it gives the following errors when I run this code. When I run the code it has a default red background color stuck in it but it should be white Background with black text color as indicated by the If-else clause in the code. What am I doing wrong?

**The errors are as follows:**

> Notice: Undefined index: BColor in /storage/ssd3/126/12156126/public_html/chookies.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: TColor in /storage/ssd3/126/12156126/public_html/chookies.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: NewBGColor in /storage/ssd3/126/12156126/public_html/chookies.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: NewTextColor in /storage/ssd3/126/12156126/public_html/chookies.php on line 17

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["chk"])) {
     $NewBGColor=$_POST['NewBGColor'];
     $NewTextColor=$_POST['NewTextColor'];   
     setcookie("BColor","$NewBGColor",time()+3600);  
     setcookie("TColor","$NewTextColor",time()+3600);
  }

 $Bcolor = $_COOKIE['BColor'];
 $TxtColor = $_COOKIE['TColor'];

  if ($Bcolor=="" || $TxtColor=="") {
     $Bcolor = "WHITE";
     $TxtColor = "BLACK";
  }
  Print "Submitted BG color " . $NewBGColor . "<br>";
  Print "Submitted Text Color ". $NewTextColor. "<br>";
  Print "BG Cookie Color ". $Bcolor . "<br>";
  Print "BG Text Color ".$TxtColor;
?>

 <html>
<head><title>Cookie</title></head>
<body bgcolor="<?Bcolor?>" Text="<?TxtColor?>">
<form method="Post" action="chookies.php" >
    Select A New BG Color:
    <Select name="NewBGColor" >
    <option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
    <option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
    <option value="RED">RED</option>
    <option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
    </Select>
    Select A New Text color:
  <Select name="NewTextColor" >
    <option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
    <option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
    <option value="RED">RED</option>
    <option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
    </Select>
    <input type="hidden" name="chk" value="true"/>
    <input type="submit"  value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the use of your hidden chk input?

Comment: you can use isset before variable or isset($NewBGColor) instead of $NewBGColor on given line number.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Since the page will submit to the same page again, it is kind of a check to see whether the page is submitted or not. so if the page is not submitted, the code will not execute.

Comment: If you want to submit to the same page remove the argument of action like so `action=""`, and you don't need that check.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I tried your suggestion, it generates further errors. didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are quite a few issues in the above code.You need to echo the colours, you should use the `style` declaration for the body tag (would be better as css!) and you ought to test that the various form elements are set in the POST array. Perhaps this might be of interest?!

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST["chk"], $_POST['NewBGColor'], $_POST['NewTextColor'] ) ) {
        setcookie( "BColor", $_POST['NewBGColor'], time()+3600 );  
        setcookie( "TColor", $_POST['NewTextColor'], time()+3600 );
    }

    $Bcolor = isset( $_COOKIE['BColor'] ) ? $_COOKIE['BColor'] : 'white';
    $TxtColor = isset( $_COOKIE['TColor'] ) ? $_COOKIE['TColor'] : 'black';

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cookie</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background:<?php echo $Bcolor;?>;color:<?php echo $TxtColor;?>">

        <form method="Post">

            Select A New BG Color:
            <Select name="NewBGColor" >
                <option value="WHITE">WHITE
                <option value="BLACK">BLACK
                <option value="RED">RED
                <option value="BLUE">BLUE
            </Select>

            Select A New Text color:

            <Select name="NewTextColor" >
                <option value="WHITE">WHITE
                <option value="BLACK">BLACK
                <option value="RED">RED
                <option value="BLUE">BLUE
            </Select>
            <input type="hidden" name="chk" value="true"/>
            <input type="submit"  value="submit" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or a slight modification that uses PHP to generate the HTML and `remember` the chosen values

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST["chk"], $_POST['NewBGColor'], $_POST['NewTextColor'] ) ) {
        setcookie( "BColor", $_POST['NewBGColor'], time()+3600 );  
        setcookie( "TColor", $_POST['NewTextColor'], time()+3600 );
    }

    $Bcolor = isset( $_COOKIE['BColor'] ) ? $_COOKIE['BColor'] : 'white';
    $TxtColor = isset( $_COOKIE['TColor'] ) ? $_COOKIE['TColor'] : 'black';

    $colours=array(
        'white','red','blue','black'
    );
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cookie</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background:<?php echo $Bcolor;?>;color:<?php echo $TxtColor;?>">

        <form method="Post">

            Select A New BG Color:
            <select name="NewBGColor" >
                <?php
                    foreach( $colours as $colour ){
                        $selected=$colour==$Bcolor ? ' selected' : '';
                        printf('<option value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s',$colour,$selected);
                    }
                ?>
            </select>

            Select A New Text color:
            <select name="NewTextColor" >
                <?php
                    foreach( $colours as $colour ){
                        $selected=$colour==$TxtColor ? ' selected' : '';
                        printf('<option value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s',$colour,$selected);
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="chk" value="true"/>
            <input type="submit"  value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: These two errors were generated when I submitted the page after selecting new colors.  Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd3/126/12156126/public_html/chookies.php:1) in /storage/ssd3/126/12156126/public_html/chookies.php on line 5

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd3/126/12156126/public_html/chookies.php:1) in /storage/ssd3/126/12156126/public_html/chookies.php on line 6

Comment: That suggests that you are printing content before using `setcookie`

Comment: the bottom code worked very well. but can the same be done with my code. thank you sir.

Comment: yes, or a similar solution can be done with your code ( either js or php ) ~ it is not so pretty without the array though. EG: in PHP for each `option` you do an inline operation such as `<option <?php if($_COOKIE['BLAH']=='BLAH')echo ' selected';?>...`

Comment: your code is very high level for me. I'm just a beginner. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: so this code, that I have written will not work because it gives the warning that says "can not modify header information already sent". should I give up on this code?

Comment: there are various functions ( and `setcookie` is one of them ) that either need to be called before any content is written to the browser / buffer or require that `output buffering` is enabled. Ideally the former is best but the latter works too.I am unclear where and how you are receiving such errors with the code I posted - please clarify what you have done.

Comment: The code that I originally posted, is fine, except for two things. First, it displays an error that says unknown variables ($BColor, $TxtColor) but after i submit it, this error is removed b/c now I have values for these variables, the other problem is that the selected colours don't work.

Comment: the code I posted does work though so you can study and adapt